# Tensorflow, IpyNotebook: Plotting a Linear Regression line

Tags: python, matplotlib, tensorflow, linear-regression

This code, linear regressiong using tensorflow, is done using Jupyter Notebook, python-3.

Code Referenced from 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44794237/tensorflow-simple-linear-regression-using-csv-data).

My csv data contains two col: Height & SoC.
I want to plot all my data points on the graph with X-axis being height, and Y-axis being SoC and then plot a best-fit line that i get from the model(shown in code below).

Values of SoC ranges from 0 to 100, values of Height ranged from 0 to 1

Both height and SoC are Float.

The current graph that i could plot(in code below), is not looking like what i want.

How do i go about plotting this specific graph? Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
rng = np.random

from numpy import genfromtxt
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.0001
training_epochs = 1000
display_step = 50
n_samples = 222

X = tf.placeholder("float") # create symbolic variables
Y = tf.placeholder("float")

filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(["battdata.csv"],shuffle=False)
reader = tf.TextLineReader() # skip_header_lines=1 if csv has headers
key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

# Default values, in case of empty columns. Also specifies the type of the
# decoded result.
record_defaults = [[1.], [1.]]
height, soc= tf.decode_csv(
    value, record_defaults=record_defaults)
features = tf.stack([height])

# Set model weights
W = tf.Variable(rng.randn(), name="weight")
b = tf.Variable(rng.randn(), name="bias")

# Construct a linear model
pred_soc = tf.add(tf.multiply(height, W), b) # XW + b <- y = mx + b  where W is gradient, b is intercept

# Mean squared error
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(pred_soc-soc, 2))/(2*n_samples)

# Gradient descent
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

# Initializing the variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
# Start populating the filename queue.
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
    sess.run(init)

     # Fit all training data
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        _, cost_value = sess.run([optimizer,cost])

        #Display logs per epoch step
    if (epoch+1) % display_step == 0:
        c = sess.run(cost)
        print( "Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(c), \
            "W=", sess.run(W), "b=", sess.run(b))

    print("Optimization Finished!")
    training_cost = sess.run(cost)
    print ("Training cost=", training_cost, "W=", sess.run(W), "b=", sess.run(b), '\n')

#Plot data after completing training
    train_X = []
    train_Y = []
    for i in range(n_samples): #Your input data size to loop through once
        X, Y = sess.run([height, pred_soc]) # Call pred, to get the prediction with the updated weights
        train_X.append(X)
        train_Y.append(Y)

    #Graphic display

    plt.plot(train_X, train_Y, 'ro', label='Original data')
    plt.ylabel("SoC")
    plt.xlabel("Height")
    plt.axis([0, 1, 0, 100])
    plt.plot(train_X, train_Y, linewidth=2.0)
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

Comment: If possible can you share the CSV file?

Comment: Here's the link for the CSV file & the ipynb file

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8Kt9KpV9HnRT0xWdVdJLWJFdWc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont understand why you say the current plot is 'not looking' the way you want.[image]

Since the same input values are mapped to multiple outputs, you can only get one representation which is close to their average using linear regression.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer, my graph output only has the "predicted data" and does not have the input value, is it possible for you to share with me the code for the plotting of input data?

Comment: The file is shared: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwoPpNIm4bJqUTRYb3lHRzlGYWs